# What happens when you create a 15-dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have the followinmg:

```
int a[100][100][100][100][100][100][100][100][100][100][100][100][100][100][100]
```

and I created a loop that would assign it some random values, and made a loop that would also output it.

My C++ book states that the array only assigns the value to the first array, and only reserves the space for the rest. How would this work? What would happen? Would the computer crash instantaneously, or eventually, or not at all? Would the memory be wiped from your computer permanently?

**NOTE:** This is for educational purposes only. I only intend to understand the
fundamentals of multi-dimensional arrays, and that's it.

Comment: Looks like you misunderstood the book. Array does not assign values, you do. Did you code it (assignment and printout loop)?

Comment: Try it and see.  My bet is it won't build unless you drop the 100 down to 2, in which case you get...a 15-dimensional array!

Comment: It will not build as is even with 2 instead of 100...

Comment: @TT_ I've coded ones with much smaller values.

Comment: It should be the same for any values, except that you can get out of memory for bigger values. Why don't you try? I think the program will crash, but that's OK for educational purposes.

Comment: @TT_ how would it work? Would it permanently have those values take loads of space in the memory? I don't want to ruin a computer..

Comment: No, you don't ruin your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C and C++, arrays are contiguous blocks of memory. This is important because it means that, just by knowing the position of the first element of the array, you can immediately jump to whatever element of the array you wish to just by supplying the offset. That's why you can index into arrays with commands like `array[4]`.

The important corollary of that in the context of this question is that all of the memory has to be assigned upon the declaration of the array. This is not so much of a problem for almost all of your normal needs, but when you get to multidimensional arrays, the required space is exponential in the number of dimensions. So the array that you're asking for is one which needs `sizeof(int)*100^15` bytes. That's 3637978807091713000 TB. The program will certainly crash upon attempting to allocate that memory.

Comment: Actually he's asking for 100^15 elements, so 4 trillion exabytes.

Comment: Yeah, saw that as soon as I posted it. Fixed now :)

Comment: Thanks for a straight-forward answer!